# Create a List of Numbers in Bogus

Tags: c#, bogus

I need to obtain a list of random positive numbers generated with Bogus.

The returned object should be the `IEnumerable<long>` type.

This will give a number, is there an easy way to generate a list using Bogus?

```
var fakeNumber = new Faker().Random.Number(0,10);
```

Comment: Can you please post the code you have so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following Bogus [documentation](https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus#using-fakert-inheritance), using Link solved my problem.
The code below gives me a list of 10 positive numbers.

```
var faker = new Faker();
var listOfNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(_ => faker.Random.Long(1)).ToList();
```

Comment: Yep, that's correct! This would be the way to do it!